# Main.Storyboard is not loaded correctly after implementing a new rootController

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication, facebook-login, login-control

I have an issue, which hasn't been fixed by now. Since I have added a feature, so that the app starts by showing the loginviewController when the user is not logged in or going directly to the userViewcontroller which represents the app functions, everything which is created in the Storyboard is not visible and the app just shows a black screen.

I am working with Firebase. I have recently added the Facebook Button, which works perfectly fine. Since it was created without the Storyboard it is the only object to be shown in the app. After the user logs in with the Facebook button, it shows a black screen again.

I have added the following code to the app delegate:

```
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    window?.rootViewController = MainViewController()
```

The MainController has the following code:

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .red

    let isLoggedIn = false

    if isLoggedIn {


    }else {

        perform(#selector(showLoginController), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.01)
    }

}

func showLoginController() {


    let loginController = LoginViewController()
    present(loginController, animated: true, completion: {

    })


}
}
```

Do you have any idea why it is not working properly?